# Using multiple levels of partitions in Hive

Tags: hive, partitioning

I am wondering if the following is possible.  I have data in Hive partitioned by date and logger, but I also have data that does not fall under a particular logger.

e.g.

```
date=2012-01-01/logger=1/part000
date=2012-01-01/logger=1/part001
date=2012-01-01/logger=2/part000
date=2012-01-01/logger=2/part001
date=2012-01-01/part000
```

I created my table with:

```
create table mytable (
    ...
)
partitioned by (date string, logger int)
....
;
```

and added partitions:

```
alter table mytable add partition (date='2012-01-01', logger=1) location '/user/me/date=2012-01-01/logger=1/';
...
```

I can query data in the partitions, but I cannot query data in the file `date=2012-01-01/part000`.  Is it possible to include this file without it conforming to the partitioning?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron, how did you manage to obtain such structure? Usually if partition key is missing HIVE creates partition called  **__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__**.

Comment: The structure resulted from moving data not originally partitioned for Hive into Hive.  The data in `date=2012-01-01/part000` is the same structure as the others, but does not have any association to a logger.  I may have to move it into a default `logger=0` to make it fit into Hive.

Comment: You will have to. Folder structure has to fit table definition. GL!

Comment: Thank you.  Your last comment was effectively the answer, so I'll accept this answer.